# Print terraform template rendered output in terminal?

Tags: terraform

In the terraform docs it shows how to use a template. Is there any way to log this rendered output the console?

https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/interpolation.html#templates

```
data "template_file" "example" {
  template = "${hello} ${world}!"
  vars {
    hello = "goodnight"
    world = "moon"
  }
}

output "rendered" {
  value = "${template_file.example.rendered}"
}
```

Comment: If you don't want an output variable you could also just `terraform state show template_file.example` and it will print all of the datasource's properties including `rendered`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to run `terraform apply` then `terraform output rendered`

```
$ terraform apply
 template_file.example: Creating...
   rendered:   "" => "<computed>"
   template:   "" => "${hello} ${world}!"
   vars.#:     "" => "2"
   vars.hello: "" => "goodnight"
   vars.world: "" => "moon"
 template_file.example: Creation complete

 Apply complete! Resources: 1 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.

 The state of your infrastructure has been saved to the path
 below. This state is required to modify and destroy your
 infrastructure, so keep it safe. To inspect the complete state
 use the `terraform show` command.

 State path: terraform.tfstate

 Outputs:

   rendered = goodnight moon!
 $ terraform output rendered
 goodnight moon!
```

Comment: Note that `terraform refresh` is sufficient; you don't have to `terraform apply`.

Comment: You don't need to do `terraform output rendered` if you have just run `terraform apply`, the variable will be output for you as shown in your answer above `Outputs: rendered = goodnight moon!` The only reason you need to run `terraform output` is if you are not running an apply, or if you want to look at the value of an output that has been marked `sensitive = true`

Answer (score 5):

watch carefully, it's data not resource

```
data "template_file" "example" {
template = "${file("templates/greeting.tpl")}"
  vars {
  hello = "goodnight"
  world = "moon"
  }
}

output "rendered" {
  value = "${data.template_file.example.rendered}"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is that code perhaps part of a module? If it is part of a module it will not be displayed. You have to put the output of the module where the module is being invoked.

Answer (score 0):

**The best answer is from Davos**

- `terraform state list` to find the resource name
- `terraform state show <resource name>`

This will work also, even when the rendered template is invalid json

*`terraform output rendered` works only, if no errors occur.*

Answer (score 0):

Note: If you specify the template as a literal string instead of loading a file, the inline template must use double dollar signs (like $${hello}).

https://www.terraform.io/language/configuration-0-11/interpolation#templates

This is how it worked:

```
data "template_file" "example" {
  template = "$${v1} $${v2}!"
  vars = {
    v1 = "hello"
    v2 = "world"
  }
}

output "rendered" {
  value = data.template_file.example.rendered

}
```

Outputs: rendered = "hello world!"